# Data Objects & classes

Tags: javascript

Hi I am just wondering I need to create multiple data object variables on lots of different JavaScript file throughout my project that all have the same keys. These object will be used as a data source for a package I have to use. for example

```
{
 V1: 0,
 V2: 0,
 V3: 0.
}
```

I was thinking of using JavaScript classes but I dont know if that is the correct way to do so. Something like

```
var i = new iVar();
```

So I created a class like so

```
class outputData {
    constructor(){
         this.O0 = 0;
         this.O1 = 0;
         this.O2 = 0;
         this.O3 = 0;
         this.O4 = 0;
         this.O5 = 0;
         this.O6 = 0;
         this.O7 = 0;
         this.O8 = 0;
         this.O9 = 0;
         this.O10 = 0;
         this.O11 = 0;
         this.O12 = 0;
    }
}
```

I then imported it into the file I wanted to use it on lie so.

```
import '../OutPutDataClass.js';

var openingDeb = new outputData();
```

But i get a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: outputData is not defined(…)
```

Not to sure why. The reason I wanted the objects initialized with data is so I can use a loop later on to iterate trough the object to call a function to set the correct values using a key and a reactive tracker. I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about doing this but I am still learning so if someone can educate me on this would be great. I have done some research on JavaScript classes but all the example create the class locally on the same file the call it from which is not what i need.

Thanks very much

Comment: I probably wouldn't use `class` until browser support for ECMA6 is much, much better....  (see https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: @BadZen: Judging by the fact they're using the `import` syntax, I'd assume they're using a transpiler.

Comment: @BadZen yes looks like you are right.What would you suggest.

Comment: @JoeClay - Click through the link I provided and check the support status of `class` in the "Compilers" tab...

Comment: @JoeClay I am using meteorJs

Comment: (In particular, meteor uses Babel, so that's the relevant column.   It shows incomplete support for `class` as of now.)

Comment: @AmyTeresaHyland: Then you should be fine - [MeteorJS handles compiling ES6 down into ES5 code](http://info.meteor.com/blog/es2015-get-started).

Comment: Hey thanks every one for you help very much appreciated keep up the good work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with your class definition (as far as I can tell, it's fine!) - it's with your understanding of how the [ES2015 import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) works. There's no 'global scope' so to speak - if you want to export/import something, you have to be explicit about it, like so:

File 1:

```
export default class OutputData {
    constructor(){
        ...
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
import OutputData from '../OutPutDataClass.js';

var openingDeb = new OutputData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the class from file to use it some where else.

**Your `OutPutDataClass.js` file:**

```
export default class outputData {
    constructor(){
         this.O0 = 0;
         this.O1 = 0;
         this.O2 = 0;
         this.O3 = 0;
         this.O4 = 0;
         this.O5 = 0;
         this.O6 = 0;
         this.O7 = 0;
         this.O8 = 0;
         this.O9 = 0;
         this.O10 = 0;
         this.O11 = 0;
         this.O12 = 0;
    }
}
```

Your file in which you want to use `outputData` class:

```
import OutputData from '../OutPutDataClass.js';

var openingDeb = new OutputData();
```

Comment: You're missing a `from` in your import.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a function with your Object as return value?
like

```
function giveMeMyObject() {
    return {V1: "value1", V2: "value2",... };
}
```